# Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, android-studio-3.0

Please tell me how to solve this error message:

```
Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel, sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}
```

My dependencies:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.maalai.maalaimatrimony"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false // Add this
        abortOnError false
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}




dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0-alpha1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0-alpha1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.0'
    implementation 'com.vinaygaba:rubberstamp:1.0.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.appyvet:materialrangebar:1.4.4'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.+'
    implementation 'com.yuyakaido.android:card-stack-view:1.0.0-beta9'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.github.drawers:SpinnerDatePicker:1.0.6'
    implementation 'com.github.florent37:expansionpanel:1.2.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'


}
```

Comment: i have experienced some issues like that while using 28.0.0 aplha1. Instead use 28.0.0 or 28.0.1. then you will see the exact error or maybe error will be gone.

Comment: No that's not working: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91

Comment: its getting new error

Comment: it is because you dont have the library except alpha1, go to sdkmanager and download latest version and try using that

Comment: yeah, i'm already downloaded latest version. but its shows same error

Comment: which version? and clean gradle cache, build folders as well

Comment: No bro. its shows same error :(

Comment: error :Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: anyone find any solution for this issue ?

Comment: yes. i'm removed "implementation 'com.github.florent37:expansionpanel:1.2.1'" this library. then its working fine